# phonegap: some click events don't work (though work in safari)

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, webview, mobile-safari

I'm testing web app using PhoneGap Develper Application (actually the same result with deployed app on iOs simulator):

Some elements in the app are not clickable (click event doesn't fire). Though it all works in mobile safari on THE SAME device. It is strange to me because web view in PG uses the same engine to render the app.

Any thoughts what can be the reason for this? This happens o iOs7 (it seems that it was working on iOs5), tested Android version is ok too.

Answer (score 0):

On backend Phonegap actually uses the instance of native browser . It is not actually any app it is instance of native (Safari ) browser. so all the actions will work fine in safari. Same is with android . In that it has chrome as it's native browser.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, I didn't included Fastclick library. It all works with Fastclick.